# Multiple (>1500) timelines- which model to use?

Tags: neural-network, time-series

I'm new to Data Science (<6 months). I'm currently working with American economic data from the BLS.

I only have quarterly numbers for about 20 years, so my timeline data isn't very wide- but I do have timelines for about 1,500 different cities/states. Most of the research on time-series data focuses on a single very wide timeline and trying to predict future data points. I'm instead trying to predict how many quarters it will take for a dip to recover.

Edit- some clarity on what I'm trying to do here:
Here is a small sample of the type of data I'm working with:

```
idx Q12000      Q22000      Q32000      Q42000      Q12001      Q22001      Q32001     Q42001      Q12002      Q22002      Q32002      Q42002

0   4085280.0   4114911.0   4108089.0   4111713.0   4055699.0   4076430.0   4043219.0  4039370.0   4201158.0   4243119.0   4231823.0   4254681.0
1   21226.0     21566.0     21804.0     22072.0     21924.0     23232.0     22748.0    22258.0     22614.0     22204.0     22500.0     22660.0     
2   96400.0     102000.0    98604.0     97086.0     96354.0     103054.0    97824.0    95958.0     115938.0    123064.0    120406.0    120648.0   
3   23820.0     24116.0     24186.0     23726.0     23504.0     23574.0     23162.0    23078.0     22306.0     22334.0     22152.0     22080.0     
4   7838.0      7906.0      7714.0      7676.0      7480.0      7520.0      7102.0     6722.0      8324.0      8166.0      8208.0      8326.0
```

Is this appropriate for an RNN or CNN? I've not seen any examples of them being used on this type of problem- but I'm also not sure what this type of problem is called, so maybe my searching isn't hitting the right keywords.

Edit: Some clarity on what I'm trying to do:

I'm looking at economic data for the past two recessions. Specifically, the number of jobs in the economy (see the third chart at this blog post calculatedriskblog.com/2012/05/…). But I have specific job number breakdowns by industry (as defined by the BLS)- so I have one time-series for each industry. For my target, I'm trying to predict how long it will take for an industry to achieve its peak job numbers before a recession. I know that's confusing, so here is a chart that hopefully will make it more clear: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyztzjjcslwrkye/Screenshot%20from%202020-12-30%2018-12-45.png?dl=0

My target is the distance between the peak and the recovery.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you target(s) and features are. However, you could look into LSTM. The low number of observations in time will likely be a problem with many methods. Did you check the Arellano-Bond model? https://jjallaire.github.io/deep-learning-with-r-notebooks/notebooks/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.nb.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arellano–Bond_estimator

Comment: @Peter Here is some clarification. I'm looking at economic data for the past two recessions. Specifically, the number of jobs in the economy (see the third chart at this blog post https://www.calculatedriskblog.com/2012/05/april-employment-report-115000-jobs-81.html). But I have specific job number breakdowns by industry (as defined by the BLS)- so I have one time-series for each industry. For my target, I'm trying to predict *how long* it will take for an industry to achieve its peak job numbers before a recession. I know that's confusing, so here is a chart that hopefully will make it

Comment: more clear (https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyztzjjcslwrkye/Screenshot%20from%202020-12-30%2018-12-45.png?dl=0)

Comment: I realize the low # of observations is a problem, but I actually have some additional dimensions to the data. I've got time-series for every county, city, and state in the US as well, and on top of that, I have industry breakdowns for each of those areas, so the actual dataset I have to work with is enormous. However I wanbt to practice with neural networks on a small chunk and get my bearings before investing in AWS to run the models. Thank you for the pointers, I'll look into them. Editing body of question to include this info.